# Why is this sentence written “Les parties du jour”?

Tags: grammaire, articles, prépositions

I came to the following sentence in English:

> Parts of the day

In French, it was written as follows:

> Les parties du jour

Why wasn't *du* written as *de*?

Answer (score 7):

In the example you give we do not use *de* on its own but it has to be followed by the definite article *le*. So it is *le jour* and not *jour*.
Sometimes you will find that *partie* is not followed by the definite article, but then it has a different meaning.

When *partie* has the meaning of "game" or designates an activity  we do not use the definite article, and thus we have :

> La partie de tennis.
>   La partie de cartes.
>   Une partie de pêche.

When *partie* has the meaning of "a part"/ "a portion" of something then we have to use the definite article (*le, la* or *les* accordingly) :

> Les parties de la maison.
>   Les parties de l'année.
>   Les parties des bâtiments réservés à l'usage des<sup>1</sup> copropriétaires.
>   La partie du<sup>2</sup>  paragraphe soulignée en rouge.

<sup>1 *des* ⇒ *de les*, compulsory elision.</sup>
<sup>2 *du* ⇒ *de le*.</sup>

Comment: J’ai, dans tes notes, un petit carré qui apparaît entre « des » et « de les » ainsi qu’un autre entre « de » et « de le ». Un caractère qui ne passe pas sur ma configuration ? Peut-il être raisonnablement remplacé par un autre ?

Comment: @Édouard: C'est une flèche  , j'en ai refait une  avec du html  (et j'ai édité mon comment parce que j'ai vu que le html &rArr; ne passe pas dans le comment) mais pas sûre du tout d'utiliser ce qu'il faut. Je mets un mot sur Cosette pour attirer l'attention des mods et autres informaticiens ! Merci de l'avoir signaler.

Comment: @Édouard C'est une flèche vers la droite. Ton navigateur a un jeu de polices incomplet. Ce n'est pourtant pas un caractère inhabituel.

Comment: En fait, lors de la septième édition, le caractère U+E25B (dans la Private Code Area) a été réécrit en flèche droite (U+2192). Cette dernière apparaît correctement dans mon navigateur ; peut-être naviguais-je encore sur une version antérieure lorsque j’ai écrit mon commentaire.

Comment: @Laure Idem dans ton commentaire, il semblerait que ce soit un U+E25B () plutôt que U+2192 (→), qui du coup n’apparaît pas chez moi.

Answer (score 3):

When *de* is followed by *le*, they contract to form *du.*

So *les parties "de le" (of the) jour* becomes *les parties du jour.*

---

Similarly, if *de* is followed by *les*, it contracts to *des*.

However, *de la* does not contract and remains as is.

Answer (score 0):

In *parts of the day*, "*the day*" is not a particular day, such as May 30, 2014. It is the **concept** *day* -- a day in the abstract.  A day - any day -- has these parts, by definition.

In English we generally do not use a definite article for this.  We typically use no article (or sometimes an indefinite article): *Man is mortal.*  In French we generally use a definite article for this: *L'homme est mortel.*